# How does AutoRecover work?

Tags: microsoft-word

Sometimes AutoRecover breaks on me and kills Word with it, but I save every minute or so anyway.

I've always wondered how it works. Does it have a temporary directory that it saves into as some secret format? Or something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there's a secret format, but Word just saves the file to a temporary location every few minutes.

You can change the auto recover save frequency - by default it's 10 minutes.

The location of the auto recover files is also configurable. By default it is

> C:\Documents and Settings[user]\Application Data\Microsoft\Word\

on Windows XP with Word 2007.

The options are accessed from **Word Options > Save** (again in Word 2007)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a MS Knowledge base article: [How Word creates and recovers the AutoRecover files](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/107686)

It's not really a "secret" format - it saves them as AutoRecover (.asd) files which, as I understand, are basically jus renamed .doc or .docx files